# Codelite Build Error

Tags: c++, build, executable, codelite

I'm using Codelite on a mac and my assignment has several different C++ programs (simple executable) to be written that aren't related to one another. I started by creating a new workspace for the all my assignments, and in that I would start a new project for each program. The problem I'm having now is that after I finish one program, when I move on to the next one and try to build and run it, it runs the first one. Should I be creating a new workspace for every different program?

Answer (score 0):

No, you just need to make sure that the project that you wish to
build is the *active* project. Creating a new project does not
automatically make it the active one.

To make a project active, double-click the project folder in the
workspace tree-view. Or right-click on the project folder and
select **Set As Active** in the menu.